# Why does smtplib not work with all email services?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

```
import smtplib 
EMAIL = 'email@email.com'
PASS_EMAIL = '**********'
email = "another@email.com"
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login(EMAIL, PASS_EMAIL)
smtpObj.sendmail(EMAIL, email, "Hello, a message for testing!")
smtpObj.quit()
```

This code works with gmail perfectly. However, it doesn't always work with yandex (sometimes I don't receive the email) and it doesn't work with mail.ru and rambler.ru at all. How can I fix it?

## dig output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.8-Debian <<>> gmail.com txt
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45942
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail.com.         IN  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmail.com.      114 IN  TXT "globalsign-smime-dv=CDYX+XFHUw2wml6/Gb8+59BsH31KzUr6c1l2BPvqKX8="
gmail.com.      114 IN  TXT "v=spf1 redirect=_spf.google.com"

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
gmail.com.      138453  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
gmail.com.      138453  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
gmail.com.      138453  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
gmail.com.      138453  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.google.com.     311240  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns2.google.com.     311240  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:34::a
ns1.google.com.     311240  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns1.google.com.     311240  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::a
ns3.google.com.     311248  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns3.google.com.     311248  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:36::a
ns4.google.com.     311248  IN  A   216.239.38.10
ns4.google.com.     311248  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:38::a

;; Query time: 12 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Ср янв 27 21:52:15 +05 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 414
```

Comment: Do you mean that yandex is the recipient's email service, or it's the service you're using instead of `smtp.gmail.com`?

Comment: @Barmar, I mean that yandex is the recipient's email service

Comment: Check if the email is going to the spam folder. Also, `email.com` might have an SPF record that doesn't include gmail servers, and yandex is checking that.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes, this letter goes to Yandex in the "Spam" folder, but it does not reach mail.ru and rambler.ru at all (which sometimes happens to Yandex as well)

Comment: Check the SPF record of your sender domain.

Comment: @Barmar, Sorry, but I'm a complete noob at this. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: `dig email.com txt` then research how SPF records work.

Comment: And if `email.com` was just an example, you should replace that with the actual sender domain you're using.

Comment: @Barmar, I added the output

Comment: I thought you said yandex was the recipient mail service. SPF is about the *sender* email. It's used to say that mail from email.com is only legitimate if it's sent from email.com's mail servers, not Gmail.

Comment: SPF stands for Sender Policy Framework.

Comment: @Barmar, Sorry, but I'm very stupid XD Changed the output for Gmail ;)

Comment: @Barmar, Oh, and how do you make it legitimate?

Comment: So is the sender email really `email@gmail.com`, not `email@email.com`?

Comment: You can't make it legal if you don't own the sender's email domain.

Comment: The whole point is that the owner of the sending domain gets to decide what servers can send email on their behalf.

Comment: @Barmar, Yes, that's just an example. Actually `@gmail.com`

Comment: Then there's nothing you can do to change it. Google controls this.

Comment: But it should always be valid to send email from gmail.com through smtp.gmail.com. So it's not an SPF problem.

Comment: You'll need to contact the mail administrators at the sites that are blocking the email to find out why. There's no general answer to questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar, It's a pity...

Comment: @Barmar, Okay, I'll try to contact them